# Multiple http calls with data transformation using angular 5

Tags: typescript, http, angular5, rxjs5

I am making a couple of similar http calls in my angular 5 application. I also need to apply similar data transformation logic and add the results to an array to display it on the page.

The 2nd call is not mandatory and is conditional.

On http subscribe, am doing the data transformation and pushing it to an array. I tried doing array concat to add the results from the 2nd call, but am not getting any results on the page.

What's the best way to approach this?

```
if(oneReq) {
     this.http.get(url).subscribe ((message:       any[]) => {
     results.push({});
     }
   return results;

} else {
    forkJoin([this.http.get(url),        this.http.get(url)]) . subscribe ((message:    any[]) => {
     results.push({});
 }
  return results;
  }
```

Comment: Share some example code. Are you using the old `Http`, or the new `HttpClient`? Are you using `promises` or `observables`.... Currently we've no idea. Downvoted.

Comment: Am using the new httpclientmodule

Comment: What change detection strategy are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use

- `forkJoin` to make all calls and wait for completion (equivalent to `Promise.all`)
- `defaultIfEmpty` for the conditionnal second call
- `map` and the spread operator to concatenate these values
- `map` again to transform these iteams

  ```
  Observable
      .forkJoin(this.first$, this.second$.defaultIfEmpty([]))
      .map(([current, added]) => [...current, ...added])
      .map(item => transform(item))
      .subscribe(array=>{
         //do something with array
      });
  ```

Comment: Code-only posts tend to get flagged as low quality and deleted.  Could you add some commentary to this so that others can understand how this fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points I can see base on the code provided:

1. Observables are asynchronous
2. You can subscribe after the conditional block

#### Asynchronous

The observable you get back from `http.get` does not emit immediately. It waits for the http response first, then executes the code inside `subscribe`. It also does not block execution. So while it's waiting for the response, it carries on and runs `return results`. When the response finally comes, then the `subscribe` block runs.

Here's an example. I've simulated Angular's `http.get` here since it's not so simple to include Angular into the snippet:

```js
// Angular's `http.get` returns an RxJS Observable
// which `emits` and `completes` when the http response comes through
// So this simulates the `get` 
// using an Observable which emits and completes after 500 milliseconds
const http = { get: () =>  Rx.Observable.of('messages').delay(500) }

const results = []
const url = ''

function getMessages() {
  http.get(url).subscribe(messages => {
    // this block is run after 500ms
    results.push({});
    console.log('C: ', results) // [{}]
  })
  return results; // this code does not wait 500ms, it runs immediately
}

const returned = getMessages()
console.log('A: ', returned) // []
console.log('B: ', results)  // []

// logs will show:
// A: []
// B: []
// C: [{}]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

### Subscribing after the conditional block

```js
const forkJoin = Rx.Observable.forkJoin

// Let's pretend our endpoint just response to `get` with the url as its "messages"
const http = {
  get(url) {
    return Rx.Observable.of([url]).delay(500)
  }
}

const url1 = 'one.com', url2 = 'two.com', url3 = 'three.com'

let results = []
let oneReq

function getMessages() {
  let response;
  if (oneReq) {
    response =  http.get(url1) // emits [one.com]
  } else {
    response = forkJoin([
      http.get(url2), http.get(url3)
    ]) //emits [[two.com], [three.com]]
  }
  
  // we return the Observable
  return response.do(handleMessages)
}

function handleMessages(messages) {
  // because of the forkJoin,
  // you need to check for the nested array
  // [[two.com], [one.com]]
  // that forkJoin makes before you concat
  results = results.concat(messages)
}

oneReq = true
getMessages().subscribe(messages => {
  console.log(results)
})

oneReq = false
getMessages().subscribe(messages => {
  console.log(results)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the `Observable` is returned from `getMessages()`.

To re-iterate on the asynchronous aspect, returning `results` from `getMessages()` will not produce what you might expect because code inside `subscribe()` executes later.

Angular components can detect the changes for you though, so you have two choices inside a component if you don't like having to subscribe to getMessages():

**Option 1:**

```
// change the `do` to subscribe
function getMessages(): void {
  // if/else...
  response.subscribe(handleMessage)
}
```

Note that you cannot return the `messages` now. Returning `response.subscribe(handleMessage)` will return the Subscription, not the Observable. [Take a look at this about subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

**Option 2:**

Use the `async` pipe in your template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let result of results | async">{{result}}</li>
<ul>
```

Here's the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) and an [article](https://juristr.com/blog/2017/06/new-enhanced-ngIf-and-ngFor/) about the async pipe

Comment: So the second request depends on the response of the first response?

Comment: No they are independent

Comment: It would really help to see some of the code you've written that isn't working.

Comment: But I couldn't help having another stab at an answer before I left work :P Updated answer to show a condition outside of the two streams

Comment: For the time being, I am using an if condition - forkjoin of 2 calls / subscribe  and in else with just http/subscribe. For some reason am not able to use a function to format the responses - I had to duplicate the logic.

Comment: I really can't visualise what you're describing. Add snippets of the if and forkjoin structure you're trying out onto your question and we can take it from there.

Comment: I have updated what I have currently which is not very clean but works. I am trying to use a function to reduce duplicate code and also want to avoid if else as well.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the code example, answer updated. Let's see if this better answers you questions